# Instance variable change affects Rails session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session-variables

In the following code, the session variable array is being changed by an operation on an instance variable. How can I stop this from happening?

```
logger.debug session[:nav_ids].count # => 30
@ids = session[:nav_ids]
@ids.shift(10)
logger.debug session[:nav_ids].count # => 20
```

Comment: Stop modifying the variable you're referencing in the session? You're setting a *reference* to the session value--it's not a separate object. You could *clone* it if you want to operate on a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone or dup the ids:

```
@ids = session[:nav_ids].clone
```

Now you can alter `@ids` without affecting `session[:nav_ids]`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are declaring the instance variable `@ids`, you are just pointing to session[:nav_ids].

You should be creating a new array:

```
@ids = Array.new(session[:nav_ids])
```

...or cloning like @zwippie suggests.